# T-SQL GROUP BY over a dynamic list

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with an XML type column. This column contains a dynamic list of attributes that may be different between records.

I am trying to GROUP BY COUNT over these attributes without having to go through the table separately for each attribute.

For example, one record could have attributes A, B and C and the other would have B, C, D then, when I do the GROUP BY COUNT I would get A = 1, B = 2, C = 2 and D = 1.

Is there any straightforward way to do this?

**EDIT** in reply to Andrew's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319530/t-sql-group-by-over-a-dynamic-list/10319968#10319968):

Because my knowledge of this construct is superficial at best I had to fiddle with it to get it to do what I want. In my actual code I needed to group by the TimeRange, as well as only select some attributes depending on their name. I am pasting the actual query below:

```
WITH attributes AS (
  SELECT 
  Timestamp,
  N.a.value('@name[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS AttributeName,
  N.a.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS AttributeValue  
  FROM MyTable
  CROSS APPLY AttributesXml.nodes('/Attributes/Attribute') AS N(a)
)
SELECT Datepart(dy, Timestamp), AttributeValue, COUNT(AttributeValue)
FROM attributes
WHERE AttributeName IN ('AttributeA', 'AttributeB')
GROUP BY Datepart(dy, Timestamp), AttributeValue
```

As a side-note: Is there any way to reduce this further?

Comment: You could move the WHERE condition up to the WITH query and maybe shave some milliseconds off it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH attributes AS (
  SELECT a.value('(.)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS attribute
  FROM YourTable
  CROSS APPLY YourXMLColumn.nodes('//path/to/attributes') AS N(a)
)
SELECT attribute, COUNT(attribute)
FROM attributes
GROUP BY attribute
```

CROSS APPLY is like being able to JOIN the xml as a table. The WITH is needed because you can't have xml methods in a group clause.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I haven't had time to try this yet, but it looks very promising. I'll let you know as soon as I get it running.

Comment: I edited my question, based on your answer. Take a look if you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to get the attribute data into a way that you can easily work with it and reduce the number of times you need to go through the main table.

```
--create test data
declare @tmp table (
    field1 varchar(20),
    field2 varchar(20),
    field3 varchar(20))

insert into @tmp (field1, field2, field3)
values ('A', 'B', 'C'),
    ('B', 'C', 'D')

--convert the individual fields from seperate columns to one column
declare @table table(
    field varchar(20))

insert into @table (field)
select field1 from @tmp
union all
select field2 from @tmp
union all
select field3 from @tmp

--run the group by and get the count
select field, count(*)
from @table
group by field
```